# adding scrollbar to div located partialview page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following div in Partial View page

```
    <div class="row">
        <div id="totalInvoiceDiv" class="col-md-6">
     </div>
   </div>
```

I want to add scrollbar to this div if its exceeding the page size, how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

Simple just set up overflow: auto; and you will able to see scroll if needed.

```
#totalInvoiceDiv {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: where should I put this in its on parial view page or Layout page